# Sony Vaio not working after reassembly

Tags: laptop, sony-vaio, laptop-repair, repair

So I have an old Sony SVE14A290X Vaio, and I have had it for a few years, recently the fan became way too loud, so I took off the laptop cover, cleaned the filter(which required me to take the heatsink off the processor, which also may have resulted in some of the thermal paste getting scraped off.), and assembled everything the way it was again, except when I press the start button, I see the Vaio logo for a few minutes, and then it shuts back down again what might have gone wrong and how do I fix it? I tried to enter the boot menu and that didn't work either. Any help is greatly appreciated. (btw, I am running windows 8)

Comment: Just basic troubleshooting/suggestions: Carefully remove everything that you took apart that has any electrical connection, inspect the connections for damage, bent pins, dust/dirt, etc and carefully reassemble. Look up what the key combination is to enter the BIOS, see if that works and if it has any diagnostic/hardware test function. Remove battery and plug in to AC power and try. If multiple ram modules, try only one at a time. Focus on what you touched first.

Comment: Re check your work